# Vagueness in the quote and notification bars

Tags: feature-request, design, blockquote

On the sites which do not have a special design, there occurs such a problem: the notification bar and the quote bar are totally indistinctive.

> [image]

It seems that this should be somehow fixed for better usability.

Comment: The report on the rus.meta: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/488/178412.

Comment: Please do not cross-post your request to multiple sites. Once is enough to be seen. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I do cross-post as it is an approved practice here, on rus.se—nobody reads our Meta and, moreover, it is in Russian. Being a moderator, I do the volunteer translation of tickets like this; so it is really strange to look at your warning. Sorry.